# Issue getting thumbnail slider to hide and show new set of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am trying to add onto an image slider I made a long time ago. I used to only have four thumbnail images under my large image. I now want more than four. I want the excess images to hide until I select the next arrow. I'm not sure of how to get the excess images show. I'm sure I have to set a max limit to show at once, but I'm not sure of where to add it. I want the set of thumbnail images to rotate by 4.

I created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1gLgg7uq/

I added in

```
//Thumb controls
$('.thumbcontrols li').click(function () {
    var
    //Slideshow
    sshow = $(this).closest('.slideshow'),
        //Increment
        incr = $(this).hasClass('prev') ? -1 : 1,
        //Current Index
        currentIndx = sshow.find('.big li').index(sshow.find('.big li:visible')),
        //Final Index
        finalIndx = currentIndx + incr;

    //Check ranges
    finalIndx = (finalIndx >= 4) ? 0 : ((finalIndx < 0) ? 3 : finalIndx);

    //Now trigger click event on respective image in nav
    sshow.find('.thumb li:eq(' + finalIndx + ')').trigger('click');
});
$('#bxslider-horizontal .bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    infiniteLoop: false,
    pager: false,
    slideWidth: 200,
    maxSlides: 4,
    minSlides: 2,
    slideMargin: 10
});
```

But I am not quote sure how to modify it to get what I need. I changed the class name of the controls so they were not the same as the large image controls.

Any ideas of what I have to do to make this work? Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the `img` under `.thumb` class using `$(".thumb img").length`. Replace the `4` (static number you set before in javascript) with the number you got as a length.

See the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//When we click on thumb img
var totalImages = $(".thumb img").length;
$('.thumb li', '.slideshow').click(function() {
    
    var
        //SlideShow
        sshow = $(this).closest('.slideshow'),
        //Big
        big = sshow.find('.big'),
        //thumb
        thumb = sshow.find('.thumb'),
        //Get index
        indx = thumb.find('li').index(this),
        //Current index
        currentIndx = big.find('li').index(big.find('li:visible'));
    
    //If currentIndx is same as clicked index won't do anything
    if(currentIndx == indx) {
        return;
    }
    
    big
        //Fadeout current image
        .find('li:visible').fadeOut().end()
        //Fadein new image
        .find('li:eq(' + indx + ')').fadeIn();
});

//When we click on any li inside controls section
$('.controls li').click(function() {
    var
        //Slideshow
        sshow = $(this).closest('.slideshow'),
        //Increment
        incr = $(this).hasClass('prev') ? -1 : 1,
        //Current Index
        currentIndx = sshow.find('.big li').index(sshow.find('.big li:visible')),
        //Final Index
        finalIndx = currentIndx + incr;
    
    //Check ranges
    finalIndx = (finalIndx >= totalImages) ? 0 : ( (finalIndx < 0) ? totalImages-1 : finalIndx);
    
    //Now trigger click event on respective image in nav
    sshow.find('.thumb li:eq(' + finalIndx + ')').trigger('click');
});
//Thumb controls
$('.thumbcontrols li').click(function() {
    var
        //Slideshow
        sshow = $(this).closest('.slideshow'),
        //Increment
        incr = $(this).hasClass('prev') ? -1 : 1,
        //Current Index
        currentIndx = sshow.find('.big li').index(sshow.find('.big li:visible')),
        //Final Index
        finalIndx = currentIndx + incr;
    
    //Check ranges
    finalIndx = (finalIndx >= totalImages) ? 0 : ( (finalIndx < 0) ? totalImages-1 : finalIndx);
    
    //Now trigger click event on respective image in nav
    sshow.find('.thumb li:eq(' + finalIndx + ')').trigger('click');
});
$('#bxslider-horizontal .bxslider').bxSlider({
                    mode: 'horizontal', 
                    infiniteLoop: false,
                    pager:false,
                    slideWidth: 200,
                    maxSlides: totalImages,
                    minSlides: 2,                
                    slideMargin: 10 
 });
});
```

```css
/*----------View Product details pic slideshow-----*/
.slideshow .big, .slideshow .controls, .thumbcontrols .slideshow .thumb {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 530px;
}
.slideshow .big li {
    position : absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
.slideshow .big li:first-child {
    display: block;
}
.slideshow .big img, .slideshow .big {
    width: 530px;
    height: 500px;
}
.slideshow .controls {
    position: absolute;
    top: 220px;
}
.thumb li.thumbcontrols {
 top: 800px;
 position: absolute;
}
.slideshow .controls li {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #666;
    opacity: .2;
    color: #ccc;
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style:none;
}
.slideshow .controls li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.slideshow .controls .next {
    float: right;
}
.slideshow .thumb img {
    width: 70px;
}
.slideshow .thumb li {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style:none;
}
.slideshow .thumb li:hover {
    opacity: .8;
}
 /*-test thumb slider-*/
 #bxslider-horizontal .bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
         -moz-box-shadow: none;
         -webkit-box-shadow: none;
         box-shadow: none;
         border: 1px solid gray;
         border-radius: 5px;
         left: 0px!important;
  padding: 5px;
         background: transparent;
         -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
         -moz-transform: translatez(0);
         -ms-transform: translatez(0);
         -o-transform: translatez(0);
         transform: translatez(0);
        }
#bxslider-horizontal .bx-wrapper{
         max-width: 845px!important;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<div class="viewproductpiccontainer">
  <div class="slideshow">
    <ul class='big'>
      <li>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/15/30/counting-149951__340.png" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/15/30/counting-149952__340.png" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/15/30/counting-149953__340.png" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/15/30/counting-149954__340.png" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/15/30/counting-149955__340.png" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/15/30/counting-149956__340.png" />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='controls'>
      <li class='prev'>&lt;</li>
      <li class='next'>&gt;</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='thumb' id="bxslider-horizontal">
      <div class="bxslider">
        <div class="slide"><li>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/15/30/counting-149951__340.png" />
        </li></div>
        <div class="slide"><li>
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/15/30/counting-149952__340.png" />
        </li></div>
        <div class="slide"><li>
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/15/30/counting-149953__340.png" />
        </li></div>
        <div class="slide"><li>
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/15/30/counting-149954__340.png" />
        </li></div>
        <div class="slide"><li>
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/15/30/counting-149955__340.png" />
        </li></div>
        <div class="slide"><li>
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/15/30/counting-149956__340.png" />
        </li></div>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <ul class='thumbcontrols'>
      <li class='prev'>&lt;</li>
      <li class='next'>&gt;</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to try adding more images, test it here.. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/pzwjy2tn/